# Error fetching queries in mongo db

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection in mongo db which looks like this:

```js
"notifications" : [
    {
        "type" : "Shout",
        "created" : ISODate("2014-04-24T13:37:02.678Z")
    },
    {
        "type" : "Shout",
        "created" : ISODate("2014-04-25T17:34:15.388Z")
    }
          ];
```

I just want to sort these notifications by created date and fetch them using mongo query but not able to do it. Can anybody help me.. Thanks..

Comment: Can you share your query ?

Comment: db.shouts.find({},{notifications:1}).sort({created: -1}).pretty()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably use aggregation framework to sort your data based on date. Here is what I tried and its working fine.

```js
db.shouts.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$notifications"}, 
  { "$sort": { "notifications.created": -1 }}, 
  { "$group": { "_id": "$_id", "notifications": { "$push": "$notifications" }}}
]);
```

and the result is:

```js
 {
     "_id" : ObjectId("5361e2cfbf5e5bf862400210"),
     "notifications" : [
         {
             "type" : "Shout",
             "created" : ISODate("2014-04-25T17:34:15.388Z")
         },
         {
             "type" : "Shout",
             "created" : ISODate("2014-04-24T13:37:02.678Z")
         }
     ]
 }
```

hope it helps